# Why isn't < working to read in a file from the command line (simple Python code)?

Tags: python, file, input, command-line

I have a simple program that reads in numbers and returns them sorted:

```
import sys

myset = set()
arguments = sys.argv[1:]

for x in arguments:
    myset.add(int(x.rstrip()))


newset = sorted(myset)
print ("sorted")

for x in newset:
    print x
```

It works perfectly when I type "python pysortints.py 1 5 6 7 2 6 7 254 2 543", but when I try something like "python pysortints.py < testfile" (when testfile is lines of pure numbers), nothing comes out except some of the print statements ("sorted").

Any ideas?  I tried rstrip on x just in case, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: try printing sys.argv ... or try printing sys.stdin.read() ... I think that sends it as stdin

Comment: This is fundamentally not a question about Python, but about how interaction between the command line and an executable actually works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do

```
pysortints.py < testfile
```

the contents of `testfile` becomes available in the standard input, not as the command line parameters.

So, you need to read the data with `raw_input` (if you are using Python 2.x) or `input` (if your are using Python 3.x) functions.

Or alternatively, you can read directly from the `sys.stdin`, like this

```
import sys
for x in sys.stdin:
    myset.add(int(x))
```

**Note:** You don't need to strip the string data being passed to `int` function. It will ignore the whitespace characters at the beginning and ending, for you :)

Lets improve the code a little bit. Your intention is to find only the unique elements and sort them. So, instead of adding elements to the set, you can use set comprehension, like this

```
{int(line) for line in sys.stdin}
```

This will get all the unique elements in int type. Next, you can simply apply `sorted` over this itself

```
print sorted({int(line) for line in sys.stdin})
```

If you want to print each and every line in new line, like you have done in your example, you can convert the sorted numbers to strings, using `map` and `str` function, like this

```
map(str, sorted({int(line) for line in sys.stdin}))
```

and then you can join them together with `\n` and print it, like this

```
print "\n".join(map(str, sorted({int(line) for line in sys.stdin})))
```

There you go! Your entire program in a single line. :) :)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I think I just got mixed up between command line input and file input.  And I'd give you extra bonus points for shortening my code if I could!

Comment: @Worcestershire Thank you :) Enjoy Python :)

Comment: `{int(line) for line in sys.stdin}` should give an error as `line` is the entire line with all numbers like '1 3 2 4 6\n'. So, `int('1 3 2 4 6\n')` will not work for me. You need to split the line.

Comment: @AndreiBoyanov I wrote that in the understanding that `is lines of pure numbers` meant numbers are in individual lines.

Comment: I agree that "is lines of pure numbers" is confusing and not clear, because it *could* imply each line only has numbers.

Comment: @thefourtheye I can agree than. As a plus, your posting was very educative.

Answer (score 3):

You need to read the `STDIN`, not the *arguments*:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
  print line.rstrip()
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to what *thefourtheye* suggests you can run your script without modifications. To do that you need to pass the content of the file as arguments (instead as standard input using '<'). You can do that with the help of the `xargs` command:

```
cat testfile | xargs python pysortints.py
```

If you still want to use the `<` redirection then pay attention to split the lines read from the file:

```
myset = set()
for line in sys.stdin:
    for x in line.split():
        myset.add(int(x))
```